# Filter using range n2-smart-table

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I am using angular 2 component ng2-smart-table and was looking for a way to filter the records by range, for example if I have an age column I would like it to be filtered like **">90 or <90"** instead of **"like '90'"**. I looked around various forums but was unable to find such a way.

Comment: When you provide the source data, you could use a pipe. Check out angular pipes.

Comment: I have yet to look into it but I was looking for something like this [filter function](https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/issues/354). I will look into angular pipes but would it be able to apply sorting based on user input dynamically? or is it a one time wonder when a a promise is returned? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I was able to apply a custom filter on the cell, doing so would call this function whenever a user would attempt to filter based on a particular column.

Example:

```
  columns: {    
    totalRows: {
    title: 'Total Rows',
    type: 'number',
    filterFunction(cell?: any, search?: string): boolean {          
      if (cell >= search || search === '') {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }          
    }
  }
```

This documentation on ng2-smart-table can be very helpful as well : [documentation](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation)

Comment: Probably just as good, and really depends when you want to filter. If you don't want the smart-table to know all your values (perhaps speed) then you might like to choose a pipe. The filter will obviously let the smart table process all values in one easy place.

Comment: This let me apply a filter based on my preference and will dynamically update the values based on user input. I didn't get a chance to look into how I can use angular pipes to achieve this behavior yet. I will look into it when I will get a chance and update the answer accordingly. Thanks for your help.